# Incorrect alignment when displaying fields using ng-repeat and ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to iterate through a list using ng-repeat and using ng-switch to select what component to show based on the data type. The problem is that, there are white spaces after SoType and Dt4 fields. Ideally, all the fields should take up equal amount of space and there should not be be any empty spaces in between.

HTML

```
  <div id="searchCriteria" class="col-xs-4"

                            ng-repeat="control in searchControls track by $index" ng-switch
                            on="control.elementType">

                            <label for="contain">{{control.name}} </label>

                                    <p ng-switch-when="calendar" class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control "
                                    uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt"
                                    is-open="values[$index]" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                                    ng-required="true" close-text="Close"
                                    alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" /> 
                                    <span
                                    class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                        ng-click="calendarOpen($index)">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </p>

                                    <p ng-switch-when="select">
                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="placement.selected"
                                    ng-options="o as o for o in control.options"></select>
                            </p>

                                        <p ng-switch-when="text">
                                <input name="ip_{{$index}}" class="form-control input-sm"
                                    ng-model="Fields[control.name]"  />
                            </p>

                        </div>
```

Controller

```
     $scope.searchControls.push({name: "Basic Product Type", elementType: "calendar",required: true});
         $scope.searchControls.push({name: "Plan Name", elementType: "text",options:['opt1','opt2','opt3']});
         $scope.searchControls.push({name: "Ben-setI", elementType: "calendar",required:true});
         $scope.searchControls.push({name: "State", elementType: "calendar",required:true});
         $scope.searchControls.push({name: "Dt1", elementType: "calendar"});
         $scope.searchControls.push({name: "SoType", elementType: "text",required: true});
         $scope.searchControls.push({name: "Dt2", elementType: "text",required: true});
         $scope.searchControls.push({name: "Dt3", elementType: "text",required: true});
         $scope.searchControls.push({name: "Plan Name", elementType: "calendar"});
         $scope.searchControls.push({name: "Dt4", elementType: "text",required:true});
         $scope.searchControls.push({name: "State of Issue", elementType: "select",required:true,options:['opt1','opt2','opt3']});
```

[image]

Comment: Where's the question and specifics of what the alignment problem is? You provided some code and an image but not connection between the two.

Comment: Can you include all of the html that makes up the image you provided.

Comment: I have added more details as to what the actual problem is. sorry about that. @charlietfl

Comment: @Michael I have added all the html code that makes up the image.

Comment: I created a code pen for this http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/ezvGGV  what is the desired results?

Comment: @Michael I want to get rid of the  white space after plan name field, which is shown here - http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/ezvGGV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove class input-sm from this block

```
<p ng-switch-when="text">
      <input name="ip_{{$index}}" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="Fields[control.name]"  />
```

in this example it works once the class is removed
http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/ezvGGV

Comment: wonderful, the problem has vanished. But what is the rationale behind this change?

Comment: you will need to review the bootstrap css to determine why the issue was happening.  I'm assuming it has something to do with padding added by that style.

Comment: Oh I figured out myself... all the components need to be consistent and have the same class and thats why input-sm needs to be removed from here. the other components just have form-control... thx